# Enumeration of connected, bridgeless, trivalent graphs

Tags: graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

Is it known how many connected, bridgeless, trivalent graphs there are on $2n$ vertices?

I am allowing the graph to have multiple edges, but no self edges (though I think the fact that the graph is trivalent and bridgeless rules out the possibility of self-edges). Here we say a graph is *bridgeless* if it does not contain any edges that would disconnect the graph if removed.

Edit: I have found [a sequence](https://oeis.org/A000421) for the number of connected, loopless, trivalent graphs on $2n$ vertices, which I believe is a super set of what I want (bridgeless $\Rightarrow$ loopless).

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in http://oeis.org/A000260. Though it's more common in this area to count *maps*, which are graphs embedded in the sphere.

Comment: Do you know a paper of Hanlon and Robinson, "Counting bridgeless graphs"?

Comment: For even orders 2, 4, ..., 18, the counts of isomorphism classes are 1, 2, 5, 16, 66, 365, 2602, 23811, 264993.  Not in OEIS.  It is plausible that labelled counts are present but I cant find them.  I believe that "bridgeless" is the same as "2-connected" in this case.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Ah, I believe you are right about bridgeless being equivalent to 2-connected. The sequence does look correct. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I did it just now.  The next value is 3449683.

Comment: Oh wow, okay. What is your strategy for computing these, may I ask? I'm not much of a combinatorialist.

Comment: following up to Sam Hopkins' comment, another related sequence is https://oeis.org/A267827, which counts isomorphism classes of rooted bridgeless trivalent maps on oriented surfaces of arbitrary genus, or equivalently, bridgeless trivalent graphs *equipped with a rooting and a cyclic ordering of the half-edges around each vertex*.

Answer (score 2):

This is about the generation problem, which is different from the theoretical enumeration problem.

One method, which is not efficient for large sizes is to use the tools **geng**  and **multig** from [nauty](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/nauty/):

**geng** -CD3 16 | **multig** -m2r3 -u

counts 23811 mutltigraphs on 16 vertices in about 10 seconds. First the 2-connected simple graphs with maximum degree 3 are made, then some edges are doubled to make it cubic. Change "-u" to "-T" if you want to see the multigraphs. It takes over an hour for 20 vertices (mostly in the first step) which is not so good.

A faster method is to make connected cubic multigraphs and reject those which are not 2-connected. An example of code to generate connected cubic multigraphs is [here](https://caagt.ugent.be/pregraphs/). The linear test for 2-connectivity is unfortunately not included but will add very little to the generation time.

The counts up to order 20 are 1, 2, 5, 16, 66, 365, 2602, 23811, 264993, 3449683.